# Firefox Webextension observer for preference change?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

Does WebExtension support internal notification (aka observer listener) for preferences?
In legacy extensions we used preference [observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Preferences#Using_preference_observers)

Basically I'm looking for a way reflect any changes to signon.rememberSignons preference at options page of a WebExtension.

Currently I'm using [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/privacy/services#Examples) code to get/set value of that preference.